# How to implement cron jobs in Windows IIS server with the help of Powershell script for ASP.NET MVC web app using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I am trying to perform cron jobs in my asp .net web app. The cron jobs have to update my MySQL database. I need an idea or a perfect example where cron jobs scripts are made in PowerShell and those scripts are run in windows IIS server task scheduler.

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho I have tried to make a dot net console application that opens my website and that console application gets executed in certain time interval through powershell script and task schedular. But i am confused in the case of database .How to perform database operations in my app . lets say i have to update my database in certain intervals. Does the similar procedure works?? Or is there any other way?

Comment: You can do the same (console App), or you can create a windows service that is executed from time to time. While you don't share some code with what you tried this question will be a opnion based question. Not the kind of question that is recommended for stack overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why don't you update this question explaining what kind of update you want to do in your MySQL? And add an example of what you thinking about how to do this. I'm trying to help you to do improve your question.